# How do I use a base class for all common entity configuration in EF Code First?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I am trying to abstract code common among my entity configuration (mapping) classes into a base class, that looks like this:

```
public class EntityWithIdTypeConfig<T>: EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T: class, IEntityWithId
{
    public EntityWithIdTypeConfig()
    {            
    }

    public EntityWithIdTypeConfig(string tableName, string schemaName)
    {
        ToTable(tableName, schemaName);
        HasKey(t => t.Id);
    }
}
```

An example entity class looks as follows:

```
public partial class Parkade: IEntityWithId
{  
    public Parkade()
    {
        this.Zones = new List<Zone>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Zone> Zones { get; set; }
}
```

This is mapped by the class:

```
public class ParkadeConfig : EntityWithIdTypeConfig<Parkade> 
{
    public ParkadeConfig(string tableName, string schemaName):base(tableName, schemaName)
    {
        HasRequired(t => t.Zones)
            .WithMany();
        Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);
    }
}
```

When I run the query, I get the error:

```
The key component 'Id' is not a declared property on type 'Parkade'.
```

where Id clearly is declared on Parkade. Is this perhaps because `Id` is an implementation of `IEntityWithId`? What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: i can't escape the same problem. So i write a function `public static void SetKey<T>(EntityTypeConfiguration<T> etc) where T : class` in which i use reflection (even here the use of an interface does not do) to look for a property Id.

Comment: It's probably cause of that config over interface. I had something similar with overriding DbContext-s and each doing it's own mappings. Do you have anything else relevant in model, mappings ?

Comment: @NSGaga I changed from an interface to a concrete base class and the problem was enough hidden :) Something in the base config class doesn't reflect on types properly and needs a 'real' `Id` property.

Comment: so it worked, solved ?